# Sharepoint 2007 extensions for Visual studio 2005

Tags: sharepoint-2007, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005 to work with Sharepoint 2007. I need sharepoint extension (VSSExtension for VS 2005).Tried in google but dint get any download link.

Can anybody post the link here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I typed `sharepoint extensions for visual studio 2005` into Google and the first result is:

> **[Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Tools: Visual Studio 2005 Extensions, Version 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15052)**
>
> Tools for developing custom SharePoint applications: Visual Studio project templates for Web Parts, site definitions, and list definitions; and a stand-alone utility program, the SharePoint Solution Generator.

Comment: That is for WSS 3.0. I got links for only WSS not for Sharepoint 2007

Comment: @karthikk: What is SharePoint 2007? Does you mean MOSS 2007 (i.e. Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007)?

Comment: @karthikk: As far I know, there is no separate version of the Extensions for MOSS, but I may be wrong. Can you point me to any resources telling that there is a separate version? Are you missing any specific features?